# Return text of dynamic @ActionLink

Tags: html, html-helper, actionlink, razor-2

I want to display in the View the actual  tag so the user can copy and save, or bookmark. ActionLink works great, but user probably not smart enough to hover over it or too scared to click on it at the moment. I have a feeling this is very simple but it escapes my feeble brain at the moment.

```
 <b>Now you can return and download your picture any time in the next 3 months. Using the link below or clicking on Download Later in navigation bar.</b>
    @Html.ActionLink("Download Link", "DownloadLater", "Home", new { photoId = Model.PhotoId, photoName = Model.PhotoName, pword = Model.PhotoPassword }, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe my question wasn't clear enough. But I figured it out. I used "Inspect" of webpage to get the html "a" tag rendered, then enhanced it from there to decide whether user was in Test or Production version. So it works dynamically correct in each. Then I realized I don't need the ActionLink at all since user might need visual assurance of the link:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Download Link Webpage", "DownloadLater", "Home", new { photoId = Model.PhotoId, photoName = Model.PhotoName, pword = Model.PhotoPassword }, null)*@
    <br />
    <br />
  <a href="http://@ViewBag.ProdOrTest/Home/DownloadLater?photoId=@Model.PhotoId&photoName=@Model.PhotoName&pword=@Model.PhotoPassword" alt="link for picture downloads"><b>http://@ViewBag.ProdOrTest/Home/DownloadLater?photoId=@Model.PhotoId&photoName=@Model.PhotoName&pword=@Model.PhotoPassword</b></a>
```